# Python: Date range into time series with corresponding values

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

My data set is much larger so I have simplified it.

I want to convert the dataframe into a time-series.

The bit I am stuck on:

I have overlapping date ranges, where I have a smaller date range inside a larger one, as shown by row 0 and row 1, where row 1 and row 2 are inside the date range of row 0.

```
df:
        date1      date2      reduction
0  2016-01-01 - 2016-01-05       7.0
1  2016-01-02 - 2016-01-03       5.0
2  2016-01-03 - 2016-01-04       6.0
3  2016-01-05 - 2016-01-12       10.0
```

How I want the output to look:

```
        date1      date2     reduction
0  2016-01-01 2016-01-02        7.0
1  2016-01-02 2016-01-03        5.0
2  2016-01-03 2016-01-04        6.0
3  2016-01-04 2016-01-05        7.0
4  2016-01-05 2016-01-06        10.0
5  2016-01-06 2016-01-07        10.0
6  2016-01-07 2016-01-08        10.0
7  2016-01-08 2016-01-09        10.0
8  2016-01-09 2016-01-10        10.0
9  2016-01-10 2016-01-11        10.0
10 2016-01-11 2016-01-12        10.0
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? I don't see any overlapping dates, so I don't really understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Is final value of date2 supposed to be 2016-01-01 in the first picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want...

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime 
first={'date1':[datetime.date(2016,1,1),datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,6),datetime.date(2016,1,7),
           datetime.date(2016,1,8),datetime.date(2016,1,9),datetime.date(2016,1,10),datetime.date(2016,1,11)],
  'date2':[datetime.date(2016,1,5),datetime.date(2016,1,3),datetime.date(2016,1,7),datetime.date(2016,1,8),
           datetime.date(2016,1,9),datetime.date(2016,1,10),datetime.date(2016,1,11),datetime.date(2016,1,12)],
  'reduction':[7,5,3,2,9,3,8,3]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(first)
blank = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(df["date1"].min(), df["date2"].max()))
blank["r1"] = blank.join(df[["date1", "reduction"]].set_index("date1"), how="left")["reduction"]
blank["r2"] = blank.join(df[["date2", "reduction"]].set_index("date2"), how="left")["reduction"]
blank["r2"] = blank["r2"].shift(-1)
tmp = blank[pd.notnull(blank).any(axis=1)][pd.isnull(blank).any(axis=1)].reset_index().melt(id_vars=["index"])
tmp = tmp.sort_values(by="index").bfill()
blank1 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(tmp["index"].min(), tmp["index"].max()))
tmp = blank1.join(tmp.set_index("index"), how="left").bfill().reset_index().groupby("index")["value"].first()
blank["r1"] = blank["r1"].combine_first(blank.join(tmp, how="left")["value"])
final = pd.DataFrame(data={"date1": blank.iloc[:-1, :].index, "date2": blank.iloc[1:, :].index, "reduction":blank["r1"].iloc[:-1].fillna(5).values})
```

Output:

```
        date1      date2  reduction
0  2016-01-01 2016-01-02        7.0
1  2016-01-02 2016-01-03        5.0
2  2016-01-03 2016-01-04        7.0
3  2016-01-04 2016-01-05        7.0
4  2016-01-05 2016-01-06        5.0
5  2016-01-06 2016-01-07        3.0
6  2016-01-07 2016-01-08        2.0
7  2016-01-08 2016-01-09        9.0
8  2016-01-09 2016-01-10        3.0
9  2016-01-10 2016-01-11        8.0
10 2016-01-11 2016-01-12        3.0
```

Comment: Your solution doens't  appear to and also isn't scaleable as you replace NaN values with 5, which wouldn't work on a much larger dataset.

Comment: Can you supply an example where it doesn't work? Even though you edited your question to an entirely different example it's still giving the expected output. I filled the NaN values with 5, because if you look at your original question. It wasn't clear at all what the value for 2016-01-05 should be, but it was 5 in your expected output.

Comment: it looks for df_new which i think should just be df?

Comment: I just fixed that :)

Comment: On the line: "blank1 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(tmp["index"].min(), tmp["index"].max()))" it returns the error Neither `start` nor `end` can be NaT

Comment: I just fixed that :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. much appreciated.